# Best solution to deploy spring batch application on AWS cloud env

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-batch, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, aws-batch

I am developing a Spring batch application and want to deploy on AWS env to ensure minimal usage of resources and as soon as the batch completes the resources should be terminated.
Please suggest me the best service for that in AWS. My job will take 1-2 hr to run.

Edit: AWS batch seems right option but not sure how inter node communication will happen as Spring batch using messaging middleware for inter node communication but AWS batch suggest to use IP based MPI, Apache MXnet etc for the same purpose